# Laravel boilerplate send object to controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am newbie with Laravel. I have just fork **laravel 5 boilerplate** from https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-5-boilerplate.

In route files, i see that there is a line like that :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user/{deletedUser}'], function () {
                Route::get('delete', 'UserStatusController@delete')->name('user.delete-permanently');
                Route::get('restore', 'UserStatusController@restore')->name('user.restore');
            });
```

I understand it means that, when url catch **'restore'** it will use function **restore** in **UserStatusController**.

And here it is:

```
public function restore(User $deletedUser, ManageUserRequest $request)
```

Can anybody can help me to find out that, how can it send object **$deletedUser** to **restore** function. Tks you!

Answer (score 3):

If your look at the route definition:

```php
user/{deletedUser}
```

That `{deletedUser}` represents the `id` of the user to be deleted/restored. Variables are declared between `{}` in routes as the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#required-parameters) states.

Now in your controller:

```php
public function restore(User $deletedUser, ManageUserRequest $request)
```

You can see that a `User` object is declared as an argument. This object is being injected by Laravel, that automatically will look for an User object that has that `id`. This is called [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding).

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding) explains it better:

> When injecting a model ID to a route or controller action, you will often query to retrieve the model that corresponds to that ID. Laravel route model binding provides a convenient way to automatically inject the model instances directly into your routes. For example, instead of injecting a user's ID, you can inject the entire User model instance that matches the given ID.

---

The same way, the `Request` class injected in this case is a `ManageUserRequest` that should be an instance of a [FormRequest](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation).

---

So, returning to your question, you will just have to specify the user id that you want to delete/restore, like this:

```php
someurl.dev/users/5     // <-- for the user of id=5
```

Now your controller will interact with that specific object to do what you want:

```php
public function restore(User $deletedUser, ManageUserRequest $request)
{
    $deletedUser->delete(); // for example
}
```

Comment: tks , your answer helps me a lot

Answer (score 1):

There are two things happening here: parameters ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters)) and model binding ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding))

First of all, in `['prefix' => 'user/{deletedUser}']` you can see that you are parsing a parameter from the url. This way, when someone navigates to `api/user/3`, laravel will pass the `3` to your route handler.

Second, it would be very nice to get the `User` model instance instead of just getting an `id` number. That's possible and it's called "model binding". Model binding can be

- Explicit

  You add your bindings to `boot` method in your `RouteServiceProvider` class, telling laravel what is the expected type of parameter.

  ```
  public function boot()
  {
      parent::boot();

      Route::model('deletedUser', App\User::class);
      // in older docs I've seen 'App\User' passed as a string instead of as a class
  }
  ```
- Implicit

  Laravel automatically figures out what model you need based on type hints.

  ```
  public function restore(User $deletedUser, ManageUserRequest $request) {}
  ```

  Here, `$deletedUser` has is type hinted as `User`. Laravel sees this, so it will go ahead and convert the `id` to the `Eloquent` model for you.

You seem to be using implicit binding, but feel free to check your `RouteServiceProvider` class.

Check the documentation links for more details, it's pretty well written. (If you are not using version 5.6, then just change the version number in the links).

Comment: tks , your answer helps me a lot

Answer (score 1):

You Just need to pass `ID` of the user as a parameter.

And this function

```
public function restore(User $deletedUser, ManageUserRequest $request)
```

you can see `$deletedUser` is of type `User` Laravel will search for that `id` (`$deletedUser`) in `Users` table and return an object of that user.

If you don't want User object and just need `ID` that you are passing in URL update `restore()` function to

```
 public function restore($deletedUser, ManageUserRequest $request)
```

Comment: tks , your answer helps me a lot